# Regroup by array by day in date property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, momentjs

How can I create a function that regroup array by day in date property

for example i have this array..

```
var _array = [ 
{name:"sample1" ,date:'08-07-2017'}, 
{name:"sample2" ,date:'08-07-2017'},
{name:"sample3" ,date:'08-08-2017'},
{name:"sample4" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
];
```

then i call the function regroup

```
regroup_byday(_array);
```

expected outputs is

```
{ 
   [
    {name:"sample1" ,date:'08-07-2017'}, 
    {name:"sample2" ,date:'08-07-2017'},
   ],

   [
   {name:"sample3" ,date:'08-08-2017'}, 
   ],

   [
    {name:"sample4" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
    {name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
    {name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
   ]
};
```

thanks in advance! ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should produce the desired output you are looking for:

```js
var _array = [
{name:"sample1" ,date:'08-07-2017'}, 
{name:"sample2" ,date:'08-07-2017'},
{name:"sample3" ,date:'08-08-2017'},
{name:"sample4" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'}
];

var regrouped = [];

for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
  var addNew = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < regrouped.length; j++) {
    if (_array[i].date === regrouped[j][0].date) {
      regrouped[j].push(_array[i]);
      addNew = false;
    }
  }
  if (addNew) {
    regrouped.push([_array[i]]);
  }
}

console.log(regrouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and push the results to an intermediary *Object* with the date as the key, and the values of the *Object* would be what you need:

```js
var _array = [ 
{name:"sample1" ,date:'08-07-2017'}, 
{name:"sample2" ,date:'08-07-2017'},
{name:"sample3" ,date:'08-08-2017'},
{name:"sample4" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
{name:"sample5" ,date:'08-09-2017'},
];

var result = Object.values(
  _array.reduce((regroup, obj) => {
    if(regroup[obj.date] === undefined) {
      regroup[obj.date] = [obj];
    } else {
      regroup[obj.date].push(obj);
    }
    return regroup;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```